# Cannot install g++6 on alpine3.9

Tags: alpine-linux, g++, couchdb

I need to install g++6 for building spidermonkey->couchdb on alpine3.9. I am unable to install it. Note that it is on the package list available on alpine 3.9 [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=g%2B%2B6&branch=v3.9).

```
$ docker run -ti alpine:3.9 sh
/ # apk add g++6
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libstdc++-8.3.0-r0:
    breaks: g++6-6.4.0-r9[libstdc++=6.4.0-r9]
    satisfies: gcc-8.3.0-r0[so:libstdc++.so.6]
  gcc-8.3.0-r0:
```